# How to Social Login with Apollo Server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, graphql, apollo

for this time I wanted to use different technologies for the back-end. So I went with `prisma`, `apollo-server`, and `typegraphql` for my graphql API. [you can find more info here](https://www.prisma.io/apollo)

After installing these packages, I wanted to make a social login with Google. After a little research I found that `passport js` & `passport-google-oauth2` is recommended for node js backends. However, almost %90 of those tutorials use `express js` and as far as I know you can't use code-first approach with express-graphql(it uses sdl-first approach and I want to try typegraphql if I can) so is there a way to implement social login to my API without using express?

### index.ts

```
import 'reflect-metadata'
import * as tq from 'type-graphql'
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server'
import { ProfileResolver, UserResolver } from './resolvers'

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

const app = async () => {
    const schema = await tq.buildSchema({resolvers: [UserResolver, ProfileResolver]})

    const server = new ApolloServer({ 
        schema,
        context: {

        }
    })

    const { url } = await server.listen(PORT)
    console.log(`Server is running at ${url}`)
}

app()
```

I can share other files if needed.

P.S: I'm a newbie at apollo and typegraphql. I followed their docs but all that written about authentication is JWT. None of them mentions social login.

Answer (score 1):

I'll be honest, I'm not too familiar with `apollo-server` or `typegraphql`, or even building a GraphQL endpoint in general. But I know some basic concepts and I'll try my best to give you a starting point to finding a solution.

Social logins typically use the [OAuth2](https://oauth.net/2/) protocol, and those tend to use JWTs for the authentication token. That's why the docs mention JWTs.

GraphQL doesn't need to know anything about an operation other than what data is expected, what data should be returned, and what actual service to call for that operation. I like to think of GraphQL as just a common interface for accessing services. It shouldn't know anything about authentication, OAuth2, etc. So whatever GraphQL endpoint that you build can call another service to handle the authentication, and return the data that you expect for authentication: a JWT, an error, etc.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, actually, I solved my problem, it turnsed out you can use code-first approach with express js.